# ReactNative:Xcode linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: react-native

after install `Google Map pods` for `iOS`. my `xcode` giving me build error clang:

> Xcode linker command failed with exit code 1.

My Podfile code is:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'sampleRN' do

  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec'
  pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket'
  ]

  pod 'GoogleMaps'  

end
```

Comment: Have you add .xcode file from node_modules to library folder in xcode for googleMap?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, there was 1 build time error and the red marker just said clang, (which gave no/ cryptic instructions on what to do)

Now, it only works when I create a new project for each individual program that I want to build.

so it is:
create new project > command line tool > enter project name > save it> write the code and press the build button.

Then, create a new project for a different bit of code.

All the other answers I read looked completely cryptic.